# Remove Head content and/or body tags found within parent page body

Tags: jquery, head

Because of my cms tool, I need to add a `<head>` and `<body>` to some include files on my site. For obvious reasons, I don't want the parent page to see the <`head>` region or `<body>` tags of the included page. The cms has a standard if, else rule I'm using on.ready to apply rules based on being logged in/out of the cms.

I'm wondering if there is a way with jquery, to within the parents body: (1) remove all `<head>` tags and all content within, and (2) remove `<body>` tags, but keep their content.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to remove the `head` and `body` of the current page, or one loaded via AJAX?

Comment: question is not clear at all. Simple test is run your page through validator... if it has more than one `head` or `body` will not validate. If page retireved via AJAX is easy to get content only

Comment: Im sorry, i though i was being very clear. lol Answer 1 below should solve my issue, but ill give it a shot later and report back. Thanks

Comment: To answer the second comment above. I am aware the page will not validate which is why I'm trying to remove the tags. To sum things up, there's content I need from some other page (not on my page) and i need to remove its head and body tags dynamically when loaded on my page (so among other things.. it will validate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes and it's called .load().
Many people seems to have problem with it, so you might have to study the question a little.
But bascily, it allows you to load a docuemnt and return only a section of it..

If you need help building the code let me know but this sould have all tha info you need.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

example show in the link

```
$('#b').load('article.html #target');
```

Basicly, i will read arctile.html to find the id #traget, and return this data in the #b element.
Simple. ;)

If on the other side, you want to remove from your CURRENT page, you can alternatively use the .remove() fucntioné

To remove the head from you CURRENT page you simply have yo do

```
 $('head').remove();
```

be aware that it will also remove the childs inside of it.

Comment: This is on the right track I think. Ill give it a shot later and provide an update. Thanks.